# How can pass value from one HTML to another in python

Tags: python, html

Have 2 html files mypage.html and page.html ,want to pass some values from one html to another and in another html how can fetch those values

Code which am using:

```
 with open('page.html', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write('<html>')
    myFile.write('<body>')
    myFile.write('<table>')
    myFile.write('<tr>')
    myFile.write('<td> Interface </td>')
    myFile.write('<td> Global </td>')
    myFile.write('</tr>')
    myFile.write('<tr>')

    myFile.write('<td> <a href="interface.html">Interface</a></td>')
    myFile.write('<td> <a href="global.html">Global</a></td>')
    myFile.write('</% print c /%>')
    #myFile.write('<var>params</var>')
    myFile.write('</tr>')
    myFile.write('</table>')
    myFile.write('</body>')
    myFile.write('</html>')

#render HTML page
with open('mypage.html', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write('<html>')
    myFile.write('<body>')
    myFile.write('<table>')
    myFile.write('<tr>')
    myFile.write('<td> Host Name </td>')
    myFile.write('<td> Result </td>')
    myFile.write('</tr>')
    myFile.write('<tr>')
    c = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
    c['mycookie'] = 'cookie_value'        
    myFile.write('<td> <a href="page.html?params="'+final_dict.keys()[0]+ '>'+final_dict.keys()[0]+'</a></td>')
    myFile.write('<td> Fail</td>')
    myFile.write('</tr>')
    myFile.write('</table>')
    myFile.write('</body>')
    myFile.write('</html>')
```

Comment: Is this question concerning the operation in the browser, or the python generation script?

Comment: Want to handle in server side

Comment: What do you mean by 'values'? Is it something you can type into a textbox in webpage 1?

Comment: Have you considered using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: @bobsterman : Meant to say,  this line (<a href="page.html?params="'+final_dict.keys()[0]+ '>'+final_dict.keys()[0]+'</a></td>')) will create link    and will go to page.html . Inside page.html ,want to have value of 'final_dict.keys()[0]'

Answer (score 0):

You have a python script which generates html. That is fine.

You are saving that html to a file and then what? Serving the file? I guess you generate the files once and then you have static files. No python code is executed when user actually requests a url. You should change that concept completely.

What you want to happen is:

1. user types a url in the browser
2. browser sends request to the server
3. server executes some python which generates html, but does not save it to a file. It just sends it back to the user
4. user sees generated html

With that approach, in step 3, python script is executed every time and you have a chance to read the request parameters.

Now, to do that, you need a server.

You could go to the absolute low-level approach, configuring Apache, IIS or whatever to serve .py files by executing python as a CGI script. That would be very similar to what you are currently doing. If you do that, you will learn a lot about how HTTP works, but it is the hard way and not optimal performance-wise

**A better option**

You can run a python web server which calls python functions to serve each configured url. Take a look at [CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/) and [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). Flask is very good, but CherryPy may be better suited for beginners.

I suggest you should start with *CherryPy*. Follow the documentation, look for tutorials...

Answer (score -1):

You can get URL parameters using the built-in array `$_GET` in php.

To retreive the parameters from the URL, you can insert this PHP code into the html source of the webpage (the one you are opening with the data in the URL):

```
<?php
 echo $_GET['key'] // Will print out the data of the given key
?>
```

Of course, you can do what you want with this data using PHP. This will only work if you are running the webpage on a web server with PHP enabled.